# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.62.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gnome-terminal, libraries

I am trying to install an ubuntu software on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.
But I get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.62.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What do I have to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're trying to install something that was built for a newer version of Ubuntu

Comment: So what can I do ( without installing the newer version of ubuntu ) ?

Comment: It depends what *"an ubuntu software"* is - you can either (1) locate a version suitable for your OS / Boost version (2) install the newer version of Boost (3) hack some symlinks to try to fool the software into thinking that your system's Boost is newer than it really is (not recommended)

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer this question without knowing the name of the software that you tried to install.